# How to Fix Python Selenium Can't Click Target Element?

Tags: python, selenium, click

My `Python Selenium` can't click target element, instead seem click element behind target element? 
I try to click, or enter text in 'drop-down meun', but I find that I am result in clicking element behind this 'drop-down.  I know this is element behind it, because there is advistering area behind, and the result top-up showing the same advistering material. Here is my code:

```
# info for login
my_email = 'my_email'
my_passcode = 'my_passcode'
email_url = r'https://www.gmx.com/#.1559516-header-navlogin2-1'

# start driver and open url
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get(email_url)

# input email account
xpath = r'//*[@id="login-email"]'
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
target = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(target).perform()
actions.click().send_keys(my_email).perform()

# input passcode and hit 'enter' to login
xpath = r'//input[@id="login-password"]'
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
target = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(target).perform()
actions.click().send_keys(my_passcode).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

It happens to me for some other site when the site appear to have 'two layers' (not sure if I am using the right word). I can process anything on top layer, and only result in activate anything behind it. Many thank when provide solution!!

Comment: does it happen when you try to click the frist or the second element?

Comment: also try to change `xpath = r'//*[@id="login-email"]'` to `xpath = r'//input[@id="login-email"]'`

Comment: What do you meann by first and second element?  I have tried both xpath, meet same issue.

Comment: try to use something like this to click something: `def klk(elem, driver):
 action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)

 driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elem)
 action.move_to_element(elem).click().perform()

 log.debug('element clicked')`

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to use this [ActionChains](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) class, all you need to do can be done using [WebElement.send_keys()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.send_keys) and [WebElement.click()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.click)
2. You don't need to re-find the element after using [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) as it returns the WebElement in case of success
3. I fail to see clickign on login button anywhere in your script, you can locate the relevant button using [XPath `contains()` function](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) like:

   ```
   xpath = r'//button[contains(@class,"login-submit")]'
   ```

   and then just call `click()` function on the resulting variable

Example suggested code:

1. You don't need to use this [ActionChains](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) class, all you need to do can be done using [WebElement.send_keys()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.send_keys) and [WebElement.click()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.click)
2. You don't need to re-find the element after using [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) as it returns the WebElement in case of success
3. I fail to see clickign on login button anywhere in your script, you can locate the relevant button using [XPath `contains()` function](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) like:

   ```
   xpath = r'//button[contains(@class,"login-submit")]'
   ```

   and then just call `click()` function on the resulting variable

Example suggested code:

```
# input email account
xpath = r'//*[@id="login-email"]'
target = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
target.send_keys(my_email)

# input passcode and hit 'enter' to login
xpath = r'//input[@id="login-password"]'
target = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
target.send_keys(my_passcode)

xpath = r'//button[contains(@class,"login-submit")]'
target = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
target.click()
```

Comment: Thank, it is working now. Other than just solution, Could you explain a bit how it work behind the code and logic? I have other code do this way like here does: 1.wait for xpath > 2. redefine xpath's element (I know not necessary now) > 3. ActionChains that do click() or send_keys. Most site still work on this way, but few site like this example doesn't work. What extra action I have added in my old way that me make result in not reaching the webelements (webelements of user and pass blank area). Many thanks